# Macbook pro mid 2012: Can I install win 8.1 UEFI or will I have driver issues?

Tags: macbook-pro

I would like to install win 8.1 along my current OSX ML on my macbook pro, mid 2012.

I was told that UEFI installs have advantages over MBR but I have also heard that might bring drivers issues because Apple did not make UEFI drivers or something like that.

What do you guys think? Is it worth it? Am I going to experience frustrating issues?

Comment: not without drivers from Appple

Comment: What do you mean? Cant I download those straight from Apple?

Answer (score 2):

Any MacBook Pro with model identifier of `MacBookPro10` or less does not have an UEFI. MacBook Pro (15 and 13 inch, Mid 2012) computers have model identifiers `MacBookPro9,1` and `MacBookPro9,3`, respectively. The MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012) has model identifier `MacBookPro10,1`. I assume your model does not have a Retina display, therefore I assume you should install using a BIOS/MBR booting.

I hear UEFI offers faster booting. I also hear this requires a single boot configuration. Well, you will being dual booting with OS X, so you can't take advantage of this feature anyway.

Another advantage to UEFI booting is access to a larger number of partitions. UEFI booting uses the GUID partitioning table (GPT). This has default limit of 128 partitions. BIOS booting requires Windows to use the MBR partitioning table. This limits Window access to only 4 partitions in  the GPT. On Mac computers, generally 3 partitions are used by OS X, leaving a single partition for Windows. There are ways around this single partition limit, but this requires abandoning the use of the Boot Camp Assistant.

Answer (score 0):

Apple either supports Windows on UEFI or BIOS on a given Mac model, but not both. They have never released drivers for both, to my knowledge. As far as I know, the 2015 Retina MacBook Pros are the first macs to not support BIOS emulation, necessitating UEFI drivers. I am not certain about older models. In order to take advantage of Apple's drivers, you have to install Windows in a configuration they support (at least when it comes to UEFI or BIOS).